# How to unit test inner function(not return) of setup in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils

I want to test like this.

#### Case 1: Error

Cannot spy the inner property because it is not a function; undefined given instead.

- Component.vue

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    function outer() {
      inner();
    }
    function inner() {
      // do something for only outer function
    }
    return { outer };
  }
};
```

- Component.spec.js

```js
it('what can I do?', () => {
  wrapper.vm.inner = jest.fn(); // throw error
  wrapper.vm.outer();
  expect(wrapper.vm.inner).toBeCalled();
});
```

#### Case 2: Error

- Component.vue

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    function outer() {
      inner();
    }
    function inner() {
      // ...
    }
    return { outer, inner }; // add inner
  }
};
```

- Component.spec.js

```js
it('what can I do?', () => {
  wrapper.vm.inner = jest.fn();
  wrapper.vm.outer();
  expect(wrapper.vm.inner).toBeCalled();
});
```

- expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

  - Expected number of calls: >= 1
  - Received number of calls:    0

#### Case 3: Pass

```js
it('what can I do?', () => {
  wrapper.vm.outer = jest.fn(() => wrapper.vm.inner());
  jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'inner');
  wrapper.vm.outer();
  expect(wrapper.vm.inner).toBeCalled();
});
```

This case is not pretty...

---

Can't I get "inner()" without including it in "return"?

These methods pass when implemented in options api. But I want to use only setup().

Answer (score -2):

#### Self Answer

I found a way. I made a class like this.

##### Util.js

```js
class Util {
  outer() {
    this.inner();
  }
  inner() {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

##### Component.vue

```js
setup() {
  const util = reactive(new Util());
  function call() {
    util.outer();
  }
  return { util, call };
}
```

#### Component.spec.js

```js
it('is this way correct?', () => {
  jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.util, 'outer');
  jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.util, 'inner');
  await wrapper.vm.call();
  expect(wrapper.vm.util.outer).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(wrapper.vm.util.inner).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: I think this approach is a little bit hacky, the best way of testing a function is to trigger it from element click, keydown, emit, or other similar actions