# Vue3- Using Vitest toHaveBeenCalled() method

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, spy, vitest

I am running a vue3 application using the Composition API and the `setup()` hook.

I am using Vitest as unit-test framework. (v 0.6.1)

I have the following sample component :

```html
// src/components/MyComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>counter : {{ counter }}</h1>
    <button
      @click="incrementCounter"
    >
      Click
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// imports
import { ref } from 'vue'

// datas
const counter = ref(1)

// methods
const incrementCounter = () => {
  if (confirm()) { // call the confirm method
    counter.value++ // increment counter by 1
  }
}

const confirm = () => {
  return true
}
</script>
```

And its test file :

```js
// src/components/MyComponent.spec.ts
import {
  shallowMount
} from '@vue/test-utils'

import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

describe('component/MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('incrementCounter method', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent) // create the wrapper
    const confirmSpy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'confirm') // create the confirm method spy
    wrapper.vm.incrementCounter() // use the incrementCounter method
    expect(wrapper.vm.counter).toBe(2) // test passed
    expect(confirmSpy).toHaveBeenCalled() // test failed
  })
})
```

The goal of the test is simply to verify if the `confirm()` method has been called inside the `incrementCounter()` method or not.

I tried to use the vitest [tohavebeencalled()](https://vitest.dev/api/#tohavebeencalled) method with a spy of the `confirm()` method but the test end up in failure with the following message:

> Re-running tests... [ src/components/MyComponent.spec.ts ]
>
> × src/components/MyComponent.spec.ts > component/MyComponent.vue >
> incrementCounter method    → expected "confirm" to be called at least
> once
>
> ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Tests 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
>
> FAIL  src/components/MyComponent.spec.ts > component/MyComponent.vue
>
> > incrementCounter method AssertionError: expected "confirm" to be called at least once  ❯ src/components/MyComponent.spec.ts:13:23
> > 11|     wrapper.vm.incrementCounter() // use the incrementCounter method
> > 12|     expect(wrapper.vm.counter).toBe(2) // test passed
> > 13|     expect(confirmSpy).toHaveBeenCalled() // test failed
> > |                       ^
> > 14|   })
> > 15| })

It seems to indicate that `confirm()` method has not been called, but since the counter value has been increased to 2, I guess it implies that the method has been effectively called in fact.

I am using the `spyOn()` method wrong? What should I do to make this test pass?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think this can help you: 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390151/how-to-unit-test-inner-functionnot-return-of-setup-in-vue3

Comment: Thank you for the hint !

It's actually possible to achiveve the test like that :
`wrapper.vm.incrementCounter = vi.fn(() => wrapper.vm.confirm());`
`vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'confirm');`
`wrapper.vm.incrementCounter();`
`expect(wrapper.vm.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();` 

But it's not super handy, specially when you working with promises and async functions. 
Using a composable function seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, the reference to `confirm` in `incrementCounter()` cannot be externally modified. That's as impossible as modifying a function's private variables.

Here's a similar vanilla JavaScript example that demonstrates what the code in your `<script setup>` is attempting (run the snippet below for demo):

```js
function setup() {
  const incrementCounter = () => {
    confirm()
  }
  const confirm = () => {
    console.log('confirm')
  }
  return {
    incrementCounter,
    confirm,
  }
}

const comp = setup()
comp.incrementCounter()

console.log('trying to update confirm...')
comp.confirm = () => console.log('Yes do it!')

comp.incrementCounter() // ❌ still calls original confirm
```

However, the properties of an object *can* be modified externally. So, a workaround is to update `incrementCounter()` to reference `confirm` *via an object*, which we'll later update:

```js
function setup() {
  const incrementCounter = () => {
   /**/
    ctx.confirm()
  }
  const confirm = () => {
    console.log('confirm')
  }
       /**/
  const ctx = {
    incrementCounter,
    confirm,
  }     /**/
  return ctx
}

const comp = setup()
comp.incrementCounter()

console.log('trying to update confirm...')
comp.confirm = () => console.log('Yes do it!')

comp.incrementCounter() // ✅ calls new confirm above
```

Using that same technique, `incrementCounter()` can refer to `confirm` via an object in `<script setup>`:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const counter = ref(1)

const incrementCounter = () => {
     /**/
  if (ctx.confirm()) {
    // call the confirm method
    counter.value++ // increment counter by 1
  }
}

const confirm = () => {
  return true
}
     /**/
const ctx = {
  confirm
}
</script>
```

Now, you can use `spyOn` on `ctx.confirm`:

```js
// MyComponent.spec.js
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

describe('component/MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('incrementCounter method', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)
                                         /**/
    const confirmSpy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm.ctx, 'confirm')
    wrapper.vm.incrementCounter()
    expect(wrapper.vm.counter).toBe(2)
    expect(confirmSpy).toHaveBeenCalled() /*✅*/
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vitest-mock-inner-function?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2F__tests__%2FMyComponent.spec.js)

Comment: Great answer. I had this same question and this helped me understand what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: @tony19,

I have 5 to 8 methods in my component which I call from another method. If a another object needs to be created with methods as its properties, there will be unnecessarily an object, also it will takes 5-18 lines of codes.
Isn't there another way to handle this?

Also, using jest instead of vitest will have the same effect.

Comment: This indeed works and it is the only solution I've found, but it looks horrible. You can't even destructure `ctx`, you have to use `ctx.whatever`.